# Temple image detection not working correctly

Tags: android, opencv

I have a picture that contains 2 icons at the bottom of the picture i'm already croping the picture to get only the buttom and comparing it with the icon picture opencv temple image detecter it works perfectly when the icon is there but the problem is when i delete the icon still the rectangle appears and it appears in wrong place all i want if there is a match show the rectangle if there is not don't show it
[image]
**here is my code**

```
public class Test123 extends AppCompatActivity {


ImageView a,b,c;
String resultImgPath,baseDir,lol;
Button x;
private static final String TAG = "Test123";
String aa,bb;

static {
    if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        Log.e(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "OpenCV loaded");
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test123);
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");

    a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    b = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    c = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    resultImgPath = baseDir+"/Test/result.jpg";


     aa = baseDir+"/Test/d.jpg";
     bb = baseDir+"/Test/dd1.jpg";
    lol = baseDir+"/Test/c.jpg";


    x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(aa);
            int fromHere = (int) (bmImg.getHeight() * 0.06);

            final  Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmImg, (int) (bmImg.getWidth() * 0.3), (int) (bmImg.getHeight() * 0.94), (int) (bmImg.getWidth() * 0.6), fromHere);
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/Test");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            String fname = "c.jpg";

            File file = new File(myDir, fname);

            if (file.exists())
                file.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                croppedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            a.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
            Bitmap bmImg2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bb);
            b.setImageBitmap(bmImg2);
            matchingDemo(lol, bb, resultImgPath, Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF);

        }
    });


}
public void matchingDemo(String imgPath,String templatePath,String resPath, int matchType){
  // to read the entered image from its path and make a mat object
    Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(imgPath);
    Mat templ = Imgcodecs.imread(templatePath);
    // Create the result matrix
    int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
    Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols,  CvType.CV_8UC3);
    // performing matching and do normalization
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, matchType);
    int type = Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO;
    Imgproc.threshold(result, result, 0.8, 1., type);
    Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
    // / finding the best match from minMaxLoc
    Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
    double bb = mmr.maxVal;
    Log.e("hey",bb+"");
    Point matchLoc;
    if (matchType == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || matchType == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
        matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
    } else {
        matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
    }
    // draw a rectangle on searched object
    Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
            matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    // store the result image here
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(resPath, img);
    Mat image = new Mat();
    image =Imgcodecs.imread(resPath);
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.cols(),image.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(image, bm);

    c.setImageBitmap(bm);
    image.release();
}
   }
```

**EDIT**

i know that i need something here

```
               if(......................)
              Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
                matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
                   }
```

I tried to put minVal inside the if block but every picture gives me different numbers i tried with normalize and without it i can put the right number on 1 picture but other picture gives me different numbers so it is not detecting at all if the icon is visible or if it is not it givin the same issue drawing in wrong place i just need 1 number or something to draw if it is there to not draw if there is no match i don't want to have value if there is no match

Comment: The issue is that template matching always gives a result, and so you're grabbing the min or max of the result every time. Even if the match is bad, you'll always find a min/maximum in the resulting image. You need to introduce a threshold so if the min/max value is too small, then you don't draw the box.

Comment: can u provide me with codes because im new in the opencv

Comment: This should be reasonably easy to implement (and I don't know Java anyways). `minMaxLoc()` returns the min/max locations *as well as the min/max values*. Simply examine the values when the detector is working correctly (i.e. when the template is present) and when it's not. Determine a threshold between these two and just simply encase everything after in an if-block (`if min_val < threshold` or `if max_val > threshold`, then draw the box).

Comment: the problem is that i  don't get the min and max values :(

Comment: you do get the min and max values. In your code you have `matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;` which gets the min value.... try checking the min value in the `mmr` object and threshold it as @AlexanderReynolds says. The same goes to the max value in `matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;`

Comment: i'm using Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF so minLoc is better for me the problem that i want if there is not a match i dont want to draw anything i don't know how to do it :(

Comment: Yes you do! I believe in you! `mmr` holds the minimum values, assuming `mmr.minVal`. Just print the values when there is a good match and print the values when there is a bad match, and you'll see the values. Then maybe set the threshold a little higher than the good match value to be less restrictive and use it in an if-block.

Comment: my double bb=mmr.minVal == 4226867.0  on this same picture (no match here) and 143073.0 with match

Comment: done i guess thanks alot

Comment: but i'm getting like -9.222809183029312E-9 in other pictures or 2.2649942E7 its is weird numbers

Comment: now the problem is that same picture but different files gives different numbers :'(

Comment: i did get the idea ur telling but like I said the main problem is now every picture that i took has different number :( i can't just put if(minVal < or > ****) do ur job in the block :'(